# PermissionSet - where are an assembly's security restrictions set?

Tags: .net, security, .net-4.0

I have inherited a solution that contains a class library with a method decorated with:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert, Name = "FullTrust")]
```

The attribute is clearly required, because if I comment out that attribute, then the method throws the following exception:

> System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

As far as I can see, the executable that references this assembly is running in full trust, beccause when I look in the executable's app.manifest, I can I see:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

As I run my Visual Studio as Administrator, I would assume that hitting debug would also run the executable in Administrator mode, so it should have full permissions (though I might be misunderstanding this entirely).

The AssemblyInfo of the library doesn't seem to have anything interesting to say about security restrictions.

So I can't see why this library is running at a lower trust level to start with.  Can someone tell me all the possible places I should look to see where this restrictive security policy is being set?

(It might be worth noting that this project was designed under .net 3.5, but my job is to upgrade it to work on 4.0 (on which it now runs).  I understand that the security model has changed significantly in the latest version.)

Answer (score 0):

OK found the answer. The security restrictions were on the AppDomain into which the assembly is loaded.  I originally thought that the assembly was called statically, but it turns out it is loaded into a new AppDomain at runtime.